# Rails alias in routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is in my routes.rb file:

```
  resources :users, :only => [:create] do
    get 'search'
    member do
      get 'images'
      get 'followers'
      get 'following'

      post 'follow'
      delete 'follow'
    end
  end
```

But I also want someone to be able to call /self/feed and /self/comments (where comment is a resource) and where self refers the the id in session. How can I do that without repeating myself?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the id is already in session, then you shouldn't need to be passing it as a URL argument. Consider the hazard of passing in the session id: what happens if an id *that is not the session id* is passed? How would you handle that?

For your comments route, you should consider something like this:

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :comments
```

Then, in the comments controller, you'd query all the comments for the id is session:

```
# app/controllers/comments_controller.rb
def index
    @comments = User.find(session[:id]).comments // assuming that the session `id` variable is the identifier for a `User` model
end
```

Consequently, all you'd need to do to access your session's comments is visit the `/comments` path.

EDIT:

To access the session's user comments via the *aliased* path `/self/comments`, you could create a named match route:

```
# config/routes.rb    
match 'self/comments' => 'user#self_comments'
```

Then, you'd add an action to your `comments_controller.rb` for `self_comments`. You can presumably reuse your comments `index.html.erb` template to render out the results:

```
# app/controllers/comments_controller.rb
def self_comments
    @comments = User.find(session[:id]).comments
    render :template => 'comments/index'
end
```

Comment: I want any user to access any other user's comments, but also (as an alias) access their own comments via /self/comments. So user # 1 could use /users/1/comments to check their own comments, /self/comments to check their own comments, or /users/2/comments to check someone else's comments.

Comment: also, if a method is called that is only allowed on the user that's logged in, is it a common practise to use a simple if check to see if the user in session is indeed the same user as the user in the path?

Comment: Ahh, I misunderstood your intent. Yes, you can alias your route to `/self/comments` by creating a match route. I've edited my answer to illustrate how that would be done. Also, it is indeed standard practice to validate that the passed id is the same as the session user's id (if that's what you're trying to assure).

Comment: Did my edited answer help? Not sure whether I've understood your question correctly or not.

Comment: Yes. Although I am wondering if there's a better DRY way of doing this. For example, self_comments method is the same comments method, only difference being that the id parameter is taken from session vs path url. Also, If for example I want to add a resources under user route, I will have to create self_.... for each method.

Comment: The final point that you brought up is a fallacy of MVC, but it's also what makes Rails work so great in non-edge cases. After all, if you already have to create a new resource each time you want to a new model, it's really not that much more work (2 lines) to add a conditional for your new model. To your first point, having a separate `self_comments` action is _actually DRYer_ than encapsulating both scenarios (session id vs. parameter id) in your `comments` action. No extra conditionals, no extraneous variable assignment. Using a separate action (only two lines of code) is the way to go.

Comment: If you think my answer helped illustrate ways to DRY up your code, would you kindly consider accepting it as correct?